# Twitter bootstrap and iPad. Div isn't wrapping the content

Tags: css, ipad, twitter-bootstrap

Issue screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I'm seeing this issue in a few of my `div`s. Everything looks fine on desktop until I test it out on an iPad.  The div does not seem to wrap my content despite my attempt to use  `< span class="clearfix" ></span>` before closing the div.

This is how the code looks like

```
<div class="span8">
      <div class="box datepickerbox"> 
        <span class="daterange_title span3">Activity summary for </span>
        <div id="reportrange" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc">
          <i class="icon-calendar icon-large"></i> <b class="caret" style="margin-top: 8px"></b>
        </div>
        <span class="clearfix"></span>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: from you images, you are missing some `clearfix` entries... and use `<div class="clearfix"></div>` or you need to change the `.clearfix` entry to be displayed as `block`.

Comment: Lovely! Thank you so much balexandre

Comment: I'll add as an anwer so you can mark it as correct answer in order that future users could see the problem and fix their code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to change is

```
<span class="clearfix"></span>
```

to

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

and Bootstrap `clearfix` rules do not specify the elemnt to be displayed as a `block` element and that's what you are missing.

Comment: didn't work on mine, but I'm using it since the beta versions and always swapped to `<div>` and always worked since :)

Comment: Good to know as an alternative if span cease to work on me as well. Thank you again. Its my first with Bootstrap. Lots to learn.